# Scroll bars for linear layout with Grid View?

Tags: android

I am having a linearlayout with some Textviews and a Gridview. Grid view will be visible on clicking one of the TextView. How can i add scroll bars for linearlayout. i have try below code but its not working how can i implement? Thanks in advance...

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView is the one that has scroll bars. If your LinearLayout exceed screen, you will see scroll bars.

If you want horizontal scroll feature, then, instead of ScrollView user HorizontalScrollView.

What is the result of code you posted?

Comment: You want to have both GridView and LinearLayout?